# Automatic textfield formatting doesn't work in iOS 7

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have some code in my app that formats values inputted by the user as they are typing. The textfield formats the input with the user's local currency symbol and decimal point type.

The issue is that while this works perfectly in iOS 8 for a lot of currencies such as Euros, Dollars, GBP etc..., it does not format properly for some of these currencies in iOS 7. I have just changed my deployment target from iOS 8 to iOS 7 and noticed this as an issue.

Here is my code:

```
    func textFieldDidChangeValue(textField: UITextField) {
    //Automatic formatting for transaction value text field. Target is added above.

    var text = textField.text.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(currencyFormatter.currencySymbol, withString: "").stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(currencyFormatter.groupingSeparator, withString: "").stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(currencyFormatter.decimalSeparator, withString: "")
    textField.text = currencyFormatter.stringFromNumber((text as NSString).doubleValue / 100.0)
    currencyDouble = (text as NSString).doubleValue / 100.0
    println(currencyDouble)

    valueEnter.alpha = 100
}
```

When I change the device's location to a European country (for Euros) and try to enter a value, the first number enters correctly but after that I cannot enter anything else nor delete the value entered.

What is different from iOS 7 to 8 in regards to this function and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that there is a strange character that is being added to the formatted text. To fix the issue you have to println the text in the textfield and copy whatever character you see between the last number and the currency symbol.

Here is my post on the developer forums if you need a better explanation: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1032392#1032392